# Error getting default device UID: '!obj'

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am getting this error in console while i m run app in simulator

> Error getting default device UID:
>   '!obj

after this error app freezes

its running on my device but when i shift my code to another system then its generating such problem I dont think there is any error in code bcz its work fine on my 1st system

Thanks

Comment: its running on my device but when i shift my code to another system then its generating such problem

I dont think there is any error in code bcz its work fine on my 1st system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> Went into System Preferences -> Sound
>   -> Output, and saw the device was set to iPhoneSimulatorAudioDevice, I
>   changed this to “Internal Speakers”,
>   rebooted, and all was well.